# com.cloudinary.http43.UploadStrategies not found in cloudinary_java jar

Tags: java, android, maven, cloudinary

when I am trying to create Cloudinary connection using following code:

```
 cloudinary = new Cloudinary("cloudinary URL");
```

this is throwing an exception:

```
   java.lang.UnknownError: Can't find Cloudinary platform adapter    [com.cloudinary.android.UploaderStrategy,com.cloudinary.http42.UploaderStrategy   ,com.cloudinary.http43.UploaderStrategy]
```

I have added the library for com.cloudinary.android.UploaderStrategy and com.cloudinary.http42.UploaderStrategy, but I could not find any library for com.cloudinary.http43.UploaderStrategy, I also searched Cloudinary Maven repositiory but it was not there. From where to find the library for com.cloudinary.http43.UploaderStrategy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should only load one of the strategies, and not all of them. see: http://cloudinary.com/documentation/java_integration#java_library_features

All JAR files are available on Maven as well: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.cloudinary%22

Let us know if the issue still persists.